# fullpage.js + handsOnTable.js slow performance on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, handsontable, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js to split the page into sections. One of the sections has a grid built with handsOnTable.js.

It works perfectly, apart from the performance in IE (all versions up to 11). When you scroll to the section with the grid, the actual scrolling is very slow, not smooth and kind of jumping. The issue does not persist in other browsers.

I assume that the scrolling is causing the grid to re-render or something like this and that affect the performance.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're entirely correct. Handsontable uses virtual rendering to only render what you can see. When you scroll, it re-renders the visible window. Unfortunately, IE never plays nice with...many things, this being one of them.

Handsontable prides themselves in their optimized solutions so if you'd like to bring this issue up on their github page, you may get some feedback. Otherwise, the answer to your implied question is:

Yes, Handsontable scrolling will work slow on IE

One solution would be to disable virtual rendering to allow for faster scrolling, however, this is not recommended as it will make the entire table re-render whenever there is a change, making the scrolling fast but the rest of the table slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ZekeDroid. Appreciate your suggestion, will try to play with the visual rendering.

Comment: How does exactly the virtual rendering works? Based on the visibiility of elemetns within the viewport?

Comment: Yeah, it will render a viewport including a few padding rows for scrolling. Essentially, Handsontable re-renders this entire viewport after almost every change you make, including scrolling.